# Automated Telnet client using commons-net

Tags: java, telnet, apache-commons-net

My requirement is to connect to some server through **telnet** using a java program and run few commands and read the responses. Based on these responses I need to perform some operation

I strated with https://stackoverflow.com/a/1213188/1025328

I'm using commons-net and my program is something like this:

```
public class TelnetSample {
    private TelnetClient telnet;
    private InputStream in;
    private PrintStream out;

    public TelnetSample(String server, int port) {
        try {
            // Connect to the specified server
            telnet = new TelnetClient();
            telnet.connect(server, port);

            in = telnet.getInputStream();
            out = new PrintStream(telnet.getOutputStream());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public String readResponse() {
        System.out.println("TelnetSample.readResponse()");

        StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                out.append(line);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println(out.toString());
        System.out.println("==========================================================");

        return out.toString();
    }

    public String read2() {
        System.out.println("TelnetSample.read()");

        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

        try {
            int available = in.available();

            for (int index = 0; index < available; index++) {
                char ch = (char) in.read();
                System.out.print(ch);
                sb.append(ch);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public String sendCommand(String command) {
        try {
            InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(command.getBytes());

            int ch;

            while ((ch = is.read()) != -1) {
                out.write(ch);
                out.flush();
            }

            System.out.println(command);

            String output = read2();

            if (output.trim().isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println("output empty");
            } else {
                System.out.println(output);
            }

            System.out.println("==========================================================");

            return output;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    public void disconnect() {
        try {
            telnet.disconnect();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            TelnetSample telnet = new TelnetSample("aspmx2.xxxxxx.com", 25);
            telnet.readResponse();

            telnet.sendCommand("Helo hi");
            telnet.sendCommand("mail from:xyz@testmail.com");
            telnet.sendCommand("rcpt to:pk@testmail.com");
            telnet.sendCommand("quit");

            telnet.disconnect();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Here apart form the telnet connection response, for every other `sendCommand` I'm getting an empty response. Can some one point me what could be the issue.

My output is something like this

```
TelnetSample.readResponse()
220 mx.xxxxxx.com ESMTP o86si4086625pfi.217 - gsmtp
==========================================================
Helo hi
TelnetSample.read()
output empty
==========================================================
mail from:xyz@testmail.com
TelnetSample.read()
output empty
==========================================================
rcpt to:pk@testmail.com
TelnetSample.read()
output empty
==========================================================
quit
TelnetSample.read()
output empty
==========================================================
```

Answer (score 1):

This code has several issue:

- the first issue is in `readResponse` method. When you use
  `readLine()` you can easy block your code and will wait forever. Please have a look at discussion [How to determine the exact state of a BufferedReader?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2124141/3800377)
- the second you don't send any CR/LF chars. Server got your requests like a single line. Ex:

> mail from:xyz@testmail.comrcpt to:pk@testmail.comquit

To fix first issue you can choose several ways:

- use multi-threading model
- use NIO API. I would recommend [Netty](http://netty.io/) for that. Especially for your case as i can see you didn't use Telnet protocol at all, you connected to SMTP server.

Quick fix but the worst, wait first line from server and go on:

```
public String readResponse() {
    System.out.println("TelnetSmtpSample.readResponse()");
    StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        out.append(reader.readLine());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println(out.toString());
    System.out.println("=====================");

    return out.toString();
}
```

To fix second one:

```
    telnet.sendCommand("Helo hi\r\n");
    telnet.sendCommand("mail from:xyz@testmail.com\r\n");
    telnet.sendCommand("rcpt to:pk@testmail.com\r\n");
    telnet.sendCommand("quit\r\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible read2 is getting a null value back from the input stream before data is actually returned.  Try something like this:

```
private String read2() {

    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

    try {
        do {
            if (in.available() > 0) {
                char ch = (char) in.read();
                sb.append(ch);
            } else {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
        } while (in.available()>0);

        String output = new String(sb);
        return output;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;

}
```